# SFTP failed to process file with name contains asterisk

Tags: java, sftp

I have a query with respect to SFTP.
I have used sftp for a file transfer functionality (in a java scheduler program).
The program would transfer a file from one location to other remote location using sftp.
All the files are getting transferred successfully except files with name contains asterisk in it.
Asterisk is considered as wildcard characters in sftp.
But, is there a way to configure sftp so that it would accept * and transfer file with name contains asterisk in it?

Any help would be appreciable.

**Note:**
I have used `com.zehon.sftp.SFTP` API as the SFTP client.
I have used the following method from this api:

```
public static int sendFile(java.lang.String localFilePath,
                           java.lang.String sftpDestFolder,
                           java.lang.String serverName,
                           java.lang.String username,
                           java.lang.String password)
                    throws FileTransferException
```

Thanks
Marshal

Comment: You did not specify what sftp program/library you are using. This is not protocol specicic but sftp client specific.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Sorry I have missed it. I have edited my question and added it as a note. Please refer it and let me know your suggestion.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Zehon is not open source and its documentation does not cover this. Did you consider using Jsch? (Zehon is just another layer on top of Jsch). Also what actually happens when you upload the file with `*`? How does it fail? Are you sure the target server allows files with `*`? Note that you cannot create file with `*` on Windows for instance.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your valuable updates and suggestions. We have solved the issue by deciding not to add asterisk in the file names. Actually I forgot to mention that we run the application in Apple MAC machine where we can create file with `*` in it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Zehon SFTP Javadoc](http://www.zehon.com/javadocs/com/zehon/sftp/SFTP.html) for that function doesn't mention anything about honoring wildcards. You should consider reporting the issue to them as a bug (a documentation bug, at least).

In the meantime, you could work around it by opening the source file yourself, and using the `sendFile()` function that takes an inputStream:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(theLocalFile)) {
    SFTP.SendFile(fis, theRemoteName, theRemoteDir,
                  theRemoteServer, theRemoteUer, theRemotePass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the filename with a backslash to get it not to interpret the asterisk as a wildcard; e.g.

```
String oldstring = "file*name";
String escaped = oldstring.replace("*", "\\*");
```

Then you use `escaped` instead of `oldstring`. Most of the jsch ftp code does mention globbing for the operations, so you have to be aware of this when using the code.